# C# разница между Array и int[]

Tags: c#, массивы, типы

Скажите в чем отличие между

```
int[] mass = new int[2] {1,2}
Array mass = new int[2] {1,2}
```

почему я не могу по индексу обращаться к элементам массива типа array?

Comment: потому что класс `Array` может представлять любой массив, в том числе многомерный. Класс `Array` это базовый тип для любого массива

Comment: для доступа по индексу у `Array` есть методы `GetValue(int)` и `GetValue(int[])`. [Источник](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.getvalue?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Comment: да, все предельно ясно, спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот смотрите.

`mass` - это ссылка на объект, так как массив - это ссылочный тип.

```cs
int[] mass = new int[2] {1, 2};
```

порождает ссылку, которая в памяти выглядит как:

```
int[] mass ---> int[]
```

То есть ссылка `mass` имеет тип `int[]` и ссылается на объект типа `int[]`.

```cs
Array mass = new int[2] {1, 2};
```

порождает ссылку, которая в памяти выглядит как:

```
Array mass ---> int[]
```

То есть в памяти будет все равно `int[]`, но ссылка будет иметь тип родителя `Array`, и в коде вы сможете с объектом работать только как с `Array`.

Можно даже так

```cs
object mass = new int[2] {1, 2};
```

```
object mass ---> int[]
```

У вас будет `mass`, но вы вообще не сможете обращаться к данным массива.

Но ситуация в обоих случаях с `Array` и `object` не безнадежная, так как можно сделать вот так:

```cs
int[] m = (int[])mass;
```

И получить

```
int[] m ---> int[]
```

Даже если `mass` был `object`. Главное, что он ссылается на объект нужного типа. Если объект, на который ссылается переменная-ссылка неподходящего типа, то вы при касте получите исключение `InvalidCastException`.

- Приведение ссылки к типу одного из родителей называется апкаст (upcast). То есть каст по иерархии наследования вверх.
- Приведение ссылки к дочернему типу называется даункаст (downcast). То есть каст по иерархии наследования вниз.

[Преобразование типов в C#](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.11.php)